# Cyanogenmod 7.1 doesn't send MMS

Tags: cyanogenmod, mms

Not sure when this started to happen, most likely after I upgraded to cyanogenmod 7.1. I was able to send/receive MMS before without any problem.

Now I can

- receive MMS at any time
- send MMS when connected to wi-fi

**my settings**

- HTC Desire
- Testra
- cyanogenmod 7.1

Any suggestions how make sending MMS possible again?

---

## UPDATE

I compared my MMS APN settings [with below one](http://whrl.pl/RcMwWW) and I had to change Authentication and I cannot find MMS Protocol in my settings thouh.

```
• Name: Telstra MMS
• APN: telstra.mms
• MMSC: http://mmsc.telstra.com:8002
• MMS proxy: 10.1.1.180
• MMS port: 80
• MMS Protocol: WAP 2.0
• MCC: 505
• MNC: 01
• Authentication: CHAP
• APN type: mms
```

I also tried all other sort of advices found on the Inet like wiping SMS/MMS settings, fixing permissions. Nothing helped.

I wonder if upgrading radio would help?

I also noticed that I have troubles to log into my sip account using CSipSimple after upgrading to 7.1.

Comment: Are youre APN Settings alright?

Comment: How can I check? I can access internet when I am not able to send MMS. At the same time I can receive MMS.

Comment: Go to "Settings > Mobile > APN (Access Point Name)". Now you see your APN. Compare it with these, add new if neccesary: http://androidforums.com/hero-support-troubleshooting/45005-mobile-network-apn-settings.html | http://blog.mobilebroadbanduser.eu/page/Worldwide-Access-Point-Name-%28APN%29-list.aspx#403 | http://www.netcomm.com.au/solutions/3g-mobile-broadband/why-use-3g-hspa/3g-carriers

Comment: The APN name is different but the values look the same to me.

Comment: Updated my question with new findings ....